# how to display Phone Number text in french as Numéro de téléphone in wpf-mvvm application

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am developing one WPF-MVVM application to support multi language(Globalization)as follows:

1. I have created one Resource manager as:

   ```
   ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("MultiLang.string", 
                                             Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
   ```
2. I have created two resx files such as string.fr.resx, string.en.resx as follows:

   In string.fr.resx, I have created one attribute as:

   ```
   Name:User_PhoneNo_Label
   Value:Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone
   ```
3. Now for example if the  user selects French language from the list, I am trying to display value for  User_PhoneNo_Label  as follows:

   ```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(sLangCode);
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(sLangCode);
   User_PhoneNo_Label = rm.GetString("User_PhoneNo_Label");
   ```

   Here sLangCode is code such as fr or en based on user selection.
4. Value for User_PhoneNo_Label in French should be displayed as "Numéro de téléphone", but now it will be displayed as "Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone".

Please let me know the solution for this problem.

Comment: Here i am asking about how to coonvert the "Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone" as "Numéro de téléphone".

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the text you want to be displayed as the value of the resource string.

Comment: Yes i am trying to display the value of the resource string as User_PhoneNo_Label = rm.GetString("User_PhoneNo_Label");. But it returns the value as "Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone" instead of "Numéro de téléphone".

Comment: @skumar: You didn't understand my answer. Don't escape the unicode characters in your resource file. Simply put the french text in there and make sure the resource file is saved as UTF-8

Comment: Here I have one file which contains french content such as "Num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone" for equivalent English text "Phone Number". So i have saved the value in the given french file into a resource file and at the time of internalizing the UI component, I am getting the value from resource file to display it in UI.  Please let me know whether my approach is correct or not.